# Unable to see animation for .transitionFlipFromRight for first 3 view controllers in array

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I have an app with a Tinder-like interface where a user can flip through car

In my `ViewController.swift`, I have

`private var currentCardsOnScreen: [CardViewController] = []`

This array gets populated as I put `CardViewController`s in the stack:

```
if !currentCardsOnScreen.map({ $0.id }).contains(vc.id) {
    self.currentCardsOnScreen.append(vc)
}
```

And items get removed after the swipe happens:

```
if let index = currentCardsOnScreen.index(of: currentCard), 
    currentCardsOnScreen.map({ $0.id }).contains(currentCard.id) {
         currentCardsOnScreen.remove(at: index)
 }
```

When the user selects a card, I run this:

```
guard let currentCard = currentCard(index: index) else { return }

currentCard.flipCard()
```

Which calls this method:

```
func flipCard() {
    guard
        let frontOfCard = frontOfCard,
        let backOfCard = backOfCard
    else { return }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.32, delay: 0, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
        if self.frontIsShowing {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)

            frontOfCard.alpha = 0
            backOfCard.view.alpha = 1
        } else {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
            frontOfCard.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)

            frontOfCard.alpha = 1
            backOfCard.view.alpha = 0
        }

        self.frontIsShowing = !self.frontIsShowing
    }, completion: nil)
```

The number of cards in the stack is always 3. For the first 3 cards, tapping the card will change the value of `frontIsShowing` but won't show the card flip. If I swipe away the first 3, any card after that will behave as intended. The animation will show and all will be good.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

**Edit:** Also, not sure if related, but on card 4 when it makes the first flip animation, I see the alphas transition via a fade in/fade out but not a card flip. On the second click is when I see that flip animation. Again, not sure if related but thought I'd mention.

Comment: What is `frontOfCard` was is `backOfCard`?

Comment: `frontOfCard` is a subclass of UIView with UIImageView, and 2 labels. If image, don't show labels. `backOfCard` is a `UIPageViewController` subclass with N pages inside of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. I had an Alamofire call to fetch a large chunk of data that was blocking the main thread from animating

Answer (score 1):

flipCard() called on main thread and fetch data on background thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     // fetch data in background thread 
});
```